# Switch for bitwise comparison

Tags: php, switch-statement, constants, bit-manipulation

I found just one entry for the keywords "bitwise switch", but I did not manage to use it because the example was written in C. In PHP I am using the following function:

```
function flags2string($flags) {
    $title = Array();
    switch(true) {
        case (MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG & $flags): 
            $title[] = 'Not null';
        case (MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG & $flags): 
            $title[] = 'Primary';
        case (MYSQLI_UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG & $flags): 
            $title[] = 'Unique';
        case (MYSQLI_NUM_FLAG & $flags): 
            $title[] = 'Number';
        break;
        default:
            $title[] = 'Other';
    }
    return implode(', ', $title);
}
```

However, it collects either just one value or, without breaks, all of them. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you need to replace & with && in your case statements.

Comment: what result you expect to get?

Comment: I don't think you should be doing this with `switch`, because the first and third `case` could be true, for example, but you can't run both without running the second one too. Use a few `if` instead.

Comment: Yes, series of if's solved my problem. Thanks.